# Track workflow precendents using only Excel Formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

what I'm trying to achieve is the following. I have a production chain, say for example:

```
A and B are used to make C
C and D are used to make E
and E is used to make F
```

And I wanna know the direct and indirect inputs of F, which would be all the others. The restriction is I can use only worksheet functions, no VBA or user defined functions.

So I built a Matrix of the direct inputs like the following. 1 means the letter in this column is a direct input for the letter of this row

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  0  0  0  0  0
B 0  0  0  0  0  0
C 1  1  0  0  0  0
D 0  0  0  0  0  0
E 0  0  1  1  0  0
F 0  0  0  0  1  0
```

And I want to transform this matrix (perharps via matrices multiplication) in a matrix that contains all the inputs, both direct and indirect and the answer would be:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
A 0  0  0  0  0  0
B 0  0  0  0  0  0
C 1  1  0  0  0  0
D 0  0  0  0  0  0
E 1  1  1  1  0  0
F 1  1  1  1  1  0
```

Any thoughts on it ? any other approach is also valid, other than the matricial one. thanks !

Comment: Ugh, I know this exact topic has been covered before, but I can't find it..

Comment: [here's a similar question](http://superuser.com/questions/526563/mapping-of-child-elements) but that's not the one I was thinking of.